# How do I retrieve featured posts using the Wordpress API (v1)?

Tags: wordpress, api, posts, wordpress-featured-image

I'm trying to use the Wordpress API (version 1 - not the new Rest API) to retrieve blog posts from various sites. However, I noticed that it was not retrieving the "featured" posts, only normal ones.

The API call I am using is: https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/$site/posts

Is there a way to retrieve *all* the posts (normal and featured)?
Thank you!

Comment: Is it posts that are tagged or categorized as 'featured'? That might help you to use the tag or categorize options on the api

Comment: Thank you for the response! I looked into this more, but I don't think it is either one. It's a yes/no option when creating the post: "Stick to the front page."

Comment: I think I found it here https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1/get/sites/%24site/posts/ under the 'sticky' option.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try that!!! Was looking around there, but I guess my mind was so set on "featured posts" that I didn't notice.

Comment: No problem, let me know if that works so I can add an answer for the the next person who is looking for a solution :)

Comment: Yes it worked!! Thanks so much again! Have a good day :')

Comment: That's awesome, glad I could help :) Please accept my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**User tried and confirmed to be working**

https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1/get/sites/%24site/posts/

There's a Query Parameter called 'sticky'.